# Generate Spring Source Endpoints with WSDL

Tags: spring, wsdl, spring-ws

Can you generate a full contract and request/response objects into Spring Source Web Service format with @EndPoint annotations from a WSDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those objects are not automatically generated. The WSDL would be the contract - there you'll find the **targetNamespace** and the **localPart**. E.g.

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="this:is.the.target:namespace" xmlns="this:is.the.target:namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xsd:element name="myLocalPart">
        <xsd:complexType>
```

The **localPart** ist the root XML element of your SOAP request payload. Now, you define an endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint {
    @PayloadRoot(namespace="this:is.the.target:namespace", localPart="myLocalPart")
    @ResponsePayload
    public void handleRequest(@RequestPayload final Element elem) {
        // do something here...
    }
```

If you've set up Spring-Ws dispatcher correctly, this would be sufficient for at least accepting the request. If you want the request to be automatically unmarshalled, you'll have to set up a marshaller/unmarshaller and define the OXM mapping somehow.

Comment: As a sidenote: you can generate the WSDL (based on an XSD), but then you'd still need to type the XSD's yourself.